# can't find sqlite3 and libsqlite3 on windows

Tags: emacs, sqlite

I have recently downloaded the SBCL - need it for a specific program Idyom

The problem is, that after carefully loading all the required, it doesn't work - in my Emacs it says:

Couldn't load foreign libraries "libsqlite3", "sqlite3". (searched CLSQL-SYS:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-SEARCH-PATHS*: NIL)
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]

I have done everything, also set up the correct path to find these files, somehow the system can't find it.

What to do? It seems, that it works perfectly on Linux and MacOs, has big problems in windows (I use win10)

Grateful for any answer!
Lorena

Comment: "I have done everything, also set up the correct path to find these files, somehow the system can't find it." does not tell us anything useful. Please edit the question to show *specifically* what you've done.